# How can I see full server request to track suspicious requests?

Tags: rules

I have very bad luck with spammers. Even though I employ both reCAPTCHA, Spamicide and BOTCHA, I get about one spammer per day, though 300 are blocked. I guess that's a pretty good ratio, but it still justifies me having to manually authorize new user accounts.

My website gets about 30K requests per day (as per access logs) of which 500 are POST requests. It runs on Drupal 6, though we are soon moving to 7.

I want to be able to see what the spammer sends when they make the request. Ideally, I would like to see the reCAPTCHA challenge they saw and what they wrote down. I'll be good with only the postdata, though.

Is there a way to achieve this using triggered rules? Is there a module which will allow me to do so (i.e. send the full request to log/email?)

Comment: Hello. To see full server request, you probably should work one level lower, at the webserver or gate step. So how is this question really Drupal related? How it would be different if you were using Wordpress or Joomla?

Comment: It's Drupal related since I want to achieve this in Drupal. Any solution would have to do with using either Drupal API or PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a module that would do this for all the different anti-spam modules. I know that the [CAPTCHA](https://drupal.org/project/captcha) module implements this for its own fields.

An alternative is a simple custom module that implements [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to target the the desired form, adds a new [submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) handler to the form and store the submitted information using [watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7).

Comment: Thanks for the Drupal API way. I found out in the meantime that BOTCHA has a logging level to allow just that. Perhaps one day I'll write this module, but not today.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at that BOTCHA logging as well. I'm especially curious since it doesn't offer a challenge similar to that of CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general solution, but it works under the configuration specified.

BOTCHA has a logging option which also logs server variables (under /admin/user/botcha, 'Log Level'). What's more, it will log the post data, so you can get both the reCAPTCHA challenge code and response.